# How to call an asp function when a submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm new to asp. I have a submit button called "search" in a file called results.asp. I just need to run an asp function called "searchRecords" in the same file as the search button when the button gets clicked. Without redirecting to another page. I tried doing everything, using js, vb script... nothing works the way I want.

the submit button:

```
<form action="what goes here?">
<input type="submit" value="Search Records" name="search">
</from>
```

the function:

```
<% function show()
...stuff here....
%>
```

Also I found this asp code from another file that works in same kind of situation, but it does not work in my file.

```
<% if (request("button name")= "button value") then
   function to call
   end if
%>
```

Please help me to figure this out... thanks in advance...

Comment: I have only worked with PHP. But they are both server-sided and I think I may know what your problem is. The "action=" part should be set to point to your search page. Let's say it's called search.asp. You also should add a method attribute. In searches, the method is usually "get". Using this, our form tag look like this: <form action="search.asp" method="get">. There is also another method: "post". Use this when you don't want the data to appear in the URL (as in passwords). You can read more on form methods here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: `if Request("search")<>"" Then
 show()
End If`

should do it.

Comment: "if Request("search")<>"" Then show() End If" I try using this line of code. but it didn't work. Still it does nothing when I click the button. Do I need to put anything inside the <form> tag ?

Comment: What you need is known as AJAX, see the two answers you got.

Answer (score 1):

With your case, I think you need to use Jquery ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:"POST" // Or GET
  data:"id=12&name=abc", 
  dataType:"xml", // Default type - text
  url:"/search/searchRecords", // URL of service
  success: function (data){ 

  }
});
```

If you use ASP.NET MVC, you can call a asp function direct. But with asp-classic, you only call a asp function through a service.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: URL + "index.php/phpService/SaveClient/" + controllerVM_.TokenKey(),
                data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(params)),
                contentType: "application/json",
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,

                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.GetClientsResponse.Result != "Invelid Tokenkey !!!") {
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location.assign("Login.html");
                    }
                },
                error: function (ErrorResponse) {

                    if (ErrorResponse.statusText == "OK") {
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("ErrorMsg:" + ErrorResponse.statusText);
                    }
                }

            });
```